# Why does margin collapsing apply to the position:abolute element?

Tags: html, css, position, margin, absolute

I've read that:

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)

> The top and bottom margins of blocks are sometimes combined (collapsed) into a single margin whose size is the largest of the individual margins (or just one of them, if they are equal), a behavior known as margin collapsing. **Note that the margins of floating and absolutely positioned elements never collapse.**

So, what can cause this behaviour?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: rgba(4, 127, 214, .3);
  position: absolute;
}

.block_2 {
  margin-top: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block_2"></div>
```

That margin-top should move my red element down in theory... Why doesn't this happen?

Comment: you never applied any margin to the absolute element so why you get surprised?

Comment: Interesting behaviour! 
The top-margin of the statically positioned element is added as a top-margin to `body` (which is regular behaviour), and if there is no ancestor element for an absoutely positioned element, it refersto `body` as a position anchor. Therefore in your example `.block_2` is top-aligned with `body`, but `body` gets a 500px top-margin from its first child `.block`

Comment: @Johannes *if there is no ancestor element for an absoutely positioned element, it refersto body as a position anchor.* --> it's not really this, there is an ancestor but there is no top or bottom value so the static position will be used as reference (adding top:0 will logically make it on the top of the screen)

Comment: @Temani Afif So, the way I look at it, you mean that without assigning coordinates (`top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right`) to the absolute positioned element, margin collapsing will work. But it's not true actually. Here's an [example.](https://jsfiddle.net/3702b5s4/) There's an absolute positioned element without assigning `top`, `bottom`..., but as I see margin collapsing doesn't work. I can't understand...

Comment: *you mean that without assigning coordinates (top, bottom, left, right) to the absolute positioned element, margin collapsing will work.* --> I never meant that and there is no relation between position:absolute and margin collapsing. Read the duplicates to understand what is happening